# Deforming path of integration from the real line to the boundary of a open subset of the upper half complex plane.

Tags: integration, general-topology, complex-analysis

Denoted the upper half of the complex plane by $\mathbb{C}^{+}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\text{Im }z>0\}$. Let the open, unbounded set $A\subseteq\mathbb{C}^{+}$ have a boundary $\partial A$ such that the boundary may be descried by a union of finitely many piecewise smooth curves in $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose $I(z)$ is sufficiently "nice", in the sense that
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}I(z)dz
\end{align*}
is well-defined, and suppose I(z) is entire. Now there is a claim that
\begin{align*}
\int_{\partial\left(\mathbb{C}^{+}\setminus A\right)}I(z)dz + \int_{\partial A}I(z)dz= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}I(z)dz.\tag{$\blacklozenge$}
\end{align*}
where $\partial A$ is oriented such that $A$ is to the left in increasing direction and similarly for $\partial\left(\mathbb{C}^{+}\setminus A\right)$. Assume that $I$ has sufficient decay properties such that all the intergrals are well-defined.

How does one prove the claim ($\blacklozenge$)?

My thoughts:

- I know that $\mathbb{R}\subseteq \partial\left(\mathbb{C}^{+}\setminus A\right) \cup \partial A$.  ([If $U\subseteq V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ then $\partial V=(\partial (V\setminus U) \cup \partial U)\cap \partial V$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398659/if-u-subseteq-v-subseteq-mathbbr2-then-partial-v-partial-v-setminus/1398680#1398680)).
- Also I feel that $\partial\left(\mathbb{C}^{+}\setminus
     A\right)\cap\mathbb{C}^{+}=\partial A\cap\mathbb{C}^{+}$ (have not
  proven yet).

(Purpose of this claim is to use that $\int_{\partial\left(\mathbb{C}^{+}\setminus A\right)}I(z)dz=0$ and ($\blacklozenge$) to show that integration over $\mathbb{R}$ may be deformed to $\partial A$.)

Comment: Is $A$ bounded? If not, the second integral in your equation might not be defined since $I$ could blow up.

Comment: @RRTT Nope, let it particularly be unbounded.Assume $I$ has sufficient decay properties.